# add array of strings into object using 2 functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, string, split

I'm creating a NoteEditor, using react. I have 2 textarea in my popup, and when i'm trying to add my array of strings into object, i have a mistake, that my variable, which is contains this arrayOfStrings returns 'undefined', when i'm clicking the button add note.

There is my function **onDescriptionChange**, i take the **e.target.value** from my textarea and add to variable **arrayOfStrings**, where **split** this string into array with words:

```
let onDescriptionChange = (e) => {
    setTextAreaHeight(e, '100px');
    let stringToSplit = e.target.value;
    let arrayOfStrings = stringToSplit.split(' ');
    return arrayOfStrings;
};
```

There is a function **addArrayToNote**, where I'm trying to add this **arrayOfStrings** into description:

```
let addArrayToNote = (arrayOfStrings) => {
    setNote({
        ...note,
        description: arrayOfStrings,
    });
    addNote();
};
```

I will be very grateful if you help...

Comment: it is not clear to me, but seems as `onDecriptionChange` is a method used to handle change in the textarea you are using, however you are returning `arrayOfString` as a result of that funcion.

when are you calling `addArrayToNode` and how are you passing the parameters.

Comment: @WistonCoronell, I thought that I should completely finish typing the words in the textarea, after which, when I click the add note button, add a description. Initially, I had everything in the `onDesriptionChange` function, however, all words were separated by a comma, there was one value in the array, and I could not put a space.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to invoke the method `addArrayToNote` after generating the **arrayOfStrings**.

```
let onDescriptionChange = (e) => {
    setTextAreaHeight(e, '100px');
    let stringToSplit = e.target.value;
    let arrayOfStrings = stringToSplit.split(' ');
    // return arrayOfStrings; instead of returning the value
    addArrayToNote(arrayOfStrings) // invoke the addArrayToNote with the strings.

};
```

```
let addArrayToNote = (arrayOfStrings) => {
    setNote({
        ...note,
        description: arrayOfStrings,
    });
    addNote();
};
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, i want to invoke the metod `addArrayToNote` after generating the `arrayOfStrings`, but the function `onDescriptionChange`  fires on every change in the textarea field, in ur help attempt, in my textarea i have words, which divided by comma, when I'm trying space them...

Comment: What method did you attach to your textarea field? If it's onChange, that's how it'd behave. Unless, you want something else.

Comment: If you want it to only fire that event after submitting the form, you'll need to separate the handler that listens to the change and one that submit the notes.

Comment: But how can i add my splitted arrayOfStrings into setNote(description)?